# Change DisplayImage while playing Mp3 file using CrossMediaManager in Xamarin forms IOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am trying to change the Display Image while playing mp3 file using CrossMediaManager, but It seems it doesn't change the image. It does change the title, id and so on, but I don't know why it can't change the display image.

```
async Task ExecutePlayChapterCommand()
        {
            if (IsBusy) return; 
            IsBusy = true;
            try
            {
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10));
                var reciter = Reciters.FirstOrDefault();
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async() => {
                    var mediaItem = await CrossMediaManager.Current.Play(reciter.DownloadURL);
                    CrossMediaManager.Current.Queue.Current.IsMetadataExtracted = false;
                    mediaItem.Title = reciter.Name;
                    var image = new Image() { Source = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri(reciter.ImagePath)) };
                    CrossMediaManager.Current.Queue.Current.Title = string.Format("{0} - {1} ({2})", "1", "ChName", "English");
                    CrossMediaManager.Current.Queue.Current.Album = reciter.Name;
                    CrossMediaManager.Current.Queue.Current.Artist = reciter.Name;
                    CrossMediaManager.Current.Queue.Current.AlbumImage = image;
                    CrossMediaManager.Current.Queue.Current.AlbumImageUri = reciter.ImagePath;
                    CrossMediaManager.Current.Queue.Current.DisplayImage = image;
                    CrossMediaManager.Current.Queue.Current.DisplayImageUri = reciter.ImagePath;
                    CrossMediaManager.Current.Queue.Current.Image = image;
                    CrossMediaManager.Current.Queue.Current.ImageUri = reciter.ImagePath;
                    CrossMediaManager.Current.Notification.UpdateNotification();
                });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            finally { IsBusy = false; }
        }
    }
```

A sample project is uploaded in [here](https://github.com/arahmancsd/SampleAudio)

Comment: Try to change the image in the main thread operation. Use  `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread()`.

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT I have with and without that but didn't worked. I uploaded a sample in Github (Updated my question).

Comment: Do you mean the image changes in collectionview?

Comment: No, When clicking the play button, the relevant image (from the url) should be shown in playback controls. Click play button and lock Android/iPhone the image should change in the Lock Screen player. Right now it shows the app icon, but it should show the relevant image. It has nothing to do with collection view.

Answer (score 0):

This answer might be a little bit late, but it worked for me perfectly.

- First, the "Image, DisplayImage" properties of the media items are objects, that contain native representations of the cover image (UIImage and Bitmap) in the platform specific projects, so do not assign them any value.
- Create your media item like this, without assigning the properties mentioned above.

  ```
        new MediaItem(chapter.MediaUrl)
        {
            ImageUri = item.ImageUrl,
            DisplayImageUri = item.ImageUrl,
            AlbumImageUri = item.ImageUrl,
            DisplayTitle = item.Title,
            Title = item.Title,
            Artist = item.Author,
            Author = item.Author,
        };
  ```
- Then, on iOS, after setting the Queue items of the media items, in the platform specific project, create a method that takes the media item. This method will be called from the shared project.
- Here is the method.

  ```
    public void SetMediaImages(IMediaManager mediaManager)
    {
        if (mediaManager.Queue != null && mediaManager.Queue.Any())
        {
            foreach (var mediaItem in mediaManager.Queue)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mediaItem.ImageUri))
                {
                    mediaItem.Image = UIImage.LoadFromData(NSData.FromUrl(new NSUrl(mediaItem.ImageUri)));
                    mediaItem.AlbumImage = mediaItem.Image;
                }
            }
        }
    }
  ```
- Call this method in your shared project using Xamarin.Form's dependency service.